# Magento 2 : Bulk update cart rule

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, gift-card

Currently in magento 2.4.2, cart rule applies to **giftcard** products also.
I need to prevent discount applied to **giftcard** product in cart.

I have two approach,

1. Bulk update cart rules, i have 1200 cart rules
   i can set condition "sku does not contain"[image]

But i am not sure how i bulk update cart rules from program (i.e script) or from db query. I need your thoughts on this.

2. Another fix would be hard code from where we can prevent discount apply to gift card product.

Any thoughts what needs to be followed here to get this feature done?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?